# How to calculate the height of this html

Tags: html, css

The `html` `height` of this element is 47px.

```css
body {
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 8px;
    display: flow-root;

} 

.div {
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  I am a body
  <div class="div"> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this because:

margin-top of body is 8px.
`line-height` is 20px and there is only one line of text.
`body`'s block-formatting-context means `div`s 11px doesn't collapse with `body`'s margin-bottom and so it expands `body` by 11px.
`body`'s margin-bottom adds 8px to expand `html`. This'd give a total of 47px.

Initially, I thought the margin-bottom of `div` would collapse with `body`'s margin-bottom as I interpreted this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) as saying block-formatting-context (BFC) didn't effect margin-bottom-collapsing.

---

Comment: you didn't read the duplicate of your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63907147/8620333 ... I gave a question that explain everything in detail. You are also answering your own question so I don't see what kind of answer are you expecting? you want us to told you: *yes* ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif 1. Although that answer looks great I find I can't read it yet because I'm shaky with some of the jargon. I'm sure it'll be useful to come & later on I'd like to query what some of it means. 2. Yes I was looking for confirmation. Is that against the rules of SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Line-height is set to a fixed height = **20px**
- Margin is 8px top + 8px bottom = **16px**
- `<div></div>` has no content, and collapses to only recognize top margin = **11px**

So, 20 + 16 + 11 = 47px